# Loop keeps getting same string

Tags: php, mysql

I can't seem to find anything on this, nor can I fix it my self after trying for hours!

The code is this:

```
function generatecode()
{
    $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    return $token;
}


$number = $_POST['number'];
$service = $_POST['service'];
$token = generatecode();
if ($service == ""){

} 
else {
    for ($x = 0; $x <= $number; $x++) {
        $con = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
        mysql_select_db("$db_name", $con);
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO tokens (id, token, service, used, usedby) VALUES(NULL, '$token','$service','0','')");
    }
}
```

The code above is suppose to generate a string randomly as many times as you want with a simple integer[POST].

When it loops it all it comes out with only 1 unique id when they're should have been (5),

and the 1 id will be the same for all the strings(`31a66b9885dba85316d399d6e898b308`), so it looks like this:

```
 - 31a66b9885dba85316d399d6e898b308 
 - 31a66b9885dba85316d399d6e898b308
 - 31a66b9885dba85316d399d6e898b308 
 - 31a66b9885dba85316d399d6e898b308
 - 31a66b9885dba85316d399d6e898b308
```

If anyone understands what i'm trying to say, please leave a comment on how to fix this, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should call the function in each iteration to get another one:

```
function generatecode() {
    $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    return $token;
}

$number = $_POST['number'];
$service = $_POST['service'];
if ($service == ""){

} 
else {
    for ($x = 0; $x <= $number; $x++) {
        $con = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
        // instead of outside, put it inside the loop
        $token = generatecode();
        mysql_select_db("$db_name", $con);
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO tokens (id, token, service, used, usedby) VALUES(NULL, '$token','$service','0','')");
    }
}
```

I'd suggest use PDO with prepared statements. In this revision, you don't need to call/connect each time, take the connection also outside, and prepare the statement, which also make your queries safer to SQL injection.

```
if (!empty($_POST['service'])){

    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $service = $_POST['service'];

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname}", $username, $password);
    $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `tokens` (id, token, service, used, usedby) VALUES(NULL, :token, :service, '0', '')");
    for ($x = 0; $x <= $number; $x++) {
        $token = generatecode();
        $insert->execute(array(
            ':token' => $token,
            ':service' => $service,
        ));
    }
} 
else {
    // do something else
}
```